# python win32print can't set custom page size

Tags: python, winapi, printing

i am trying to print pdf file with custom page size in python with win32print i can change other setting like number of  copies but setting custom page length and width is not working it always try to fit pdf content into page by covering whole page this is my code

```
printers=win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL)
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
temprint=printers[1][2]
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(temprint, PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
level = 2
attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperWidth = 600  
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperLength = 30  
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperSize =0 
print(win32print.SetPrinter(handle, level, attributes, 0))
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'printto','test.pdf','"%s"' % temprint,'.',0)
win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
```

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: What's the return value of `SetPrinter`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this also applies in this case. But from the class [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printerconfiguration), I remember that the values for the mentioned attributes were assigned as `(Tenths of a millimeter)`.

Your values here don't correspond to that

```
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperWidth = 600  
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperLength = 30  
attributes['pDevMode'].PaperSize =0
```

Comment: i want to print on custom page with size 520*111mm can you explain how can i do it here

Comment: You would want to adjust your values in compliance with the docs. Again, I am not sure if this will fix but you may try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Access type for PaperWidth is ReadOnly?

PaperWidth
Data type: uint32
Access type: Read-only
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printerconfiguration